# last Q but Edited: when application Activities destroyed, I got the onDestroy of the Service that supposed to run forever

Tags: android, service

my application uses a **service** in the mode `START_STICKY`,everything work fine,

**PROBLEM**

Just when my activity Ends, the Service Return START_STICKY from onStartCommand,**and destroy it self** calling its own onDestroy... after that the service re-start and continue forever, but my problem is with the return from onStartCommand (and self destroy) that causes all my input streams,output streams and the socket close! and thus make the server got **exception** (**java.net.SocketException**: Software caused connection abort: socket write error).
    how may I avoid the onDestroy of the service when closing the activities!?

my code is very separated and big so I ask about the concept, not the coding errors!

Comment: Are you asking about how to unbind a Service from an Activity?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your Service as its own process otherwise, the Service will belong to you application process and when that process is killed, apparently your Service will be killed too. This article will help: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html